# sum of infinite roots?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, radicals, nested-radicals

What is the sum of this infinite series of roots:
$$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4 + \cdots+\sqrt{\infty}}}}}$$

This is an interesting expression because the increase created by the addition of the next term is offset by the square root introduced with the next term. the key is determining what the relationship between these two is exactly

I know it converges on an irrational number around 1.75 as I have tried computing it for a few small iterations. But I was wondering how to algebraically simplify this expression.

I have tried many things and ways to manipulate the expression but to no avail.

Comment: Can you prove that the expression actually converges?

Comment: no i cant, i only assumed

Comment: To show convergence, see: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HerschfeldsConvergenceTheorem.html. But after that, how do you even know that the number is irrational?

Comment: Actually, it is not known whether this number is irrational.

Comment: The $\large\infty$ in the formula avoids  to write $\large n$ and put in from of it the $\large\lim_{n \to \infty}$. It's clearly understood, by people who know have 'to read between lines' ,that is a short cut. You can leave it there.

Answer (score 3):

This is the [Nested Radical Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html)
, which does converge, but whose closed-form expression is still unknown. See also [Somos's Quadratic Recurrence Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SomossQuadraticRecurrenceConstant.html)
 for a similar constant, involving their product.